# "Uncaught [object Object]" when running karma tests on Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, google-chrome-headless

I am fighting with this strange error when running unit tests for my application.

```
zone.js:260 Uncaught [object Object] thrown
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:260
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:423
```

I dont know which test is failing cause the console only drop that error. It is not hapenning in my local, where the tests run whithout any problem.

Before that error i was suffering the "Script error" error but I solved it with the --disable-web-security flag for ChromeHeadless. I dont know if it has something to do with this new error.

Both my locale en the remote are linux.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Justin finally i solved it. It seemed to be a problema with the MockBackend module... if i don't use it,the error doesnt appear. I just used another methods for testing http calls.

Comment: We also traced our issue to HTTP requests. See full answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101519/karma-start-fails-headlesschrome-error-uncaught-object-object?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

You might have different versions of modules installed on the remote, or different versions of global npm packages. Any mismatched version of dependency can yield a different result on either machine.

Purge your npm cache on both machines:

```
npm cache clean
```

Reinstall your `node_modules` on both machines:

```
rm -fr node_modules
npm install
```

Verify the local npm packages are the same on each machine

```
npm list --depth=0
```

Verify global package versions are the same. You can list global packages like this

```
 npm list -g --depth=0
```

Once you have everything the same. You should see the same result on both machines.

Start by trying to run karma

```
  karma start
```

If that works, next run each test separately.

```
  karma run -- --grep=search_string
```

If the error is preventing you from starting karma. Check the startup scripts for tests, and see if you can comment out modules from your Angular app. Keep reducing the dependencies until you get Karma running. Reintroduce the dependencies slowly until you find the offender.