# Karma Start Fails - HeadlessChrome - ERROR Uncaught [object Object]

Tags: angular, karma-runner, travis-ci

I am using Karma to run test on my Angular 4 app. **It works locally** but when it runs on my host environment (Travis CI) it fails with the following information:

```
INFO [HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket vT0QnQaqRkn010dfsw with id 10189531

HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 180 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)

e 0.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 180 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.714 secs)

HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) ERROR

  Uncaught [object Object]

  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:14078
```

I tried following the suggestions (deleting NPM cache, etc) from ["Uncaught [object Object]" when running karma tests on Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873996/uncaught-object-object-when-running-karma-tests-on-angular) but it did not solve my issue.

How can I identify what is causing this `Uncaught [object Object]` error. What additional steps should I take to troubleshoot?

Comment: What is your second test locally? It seems this fails at the second test, that the first one was successful.

Comment: Test 1 just verifys true=true, the second test starts verifying elements on the DOM, I tried disabling test 2 and then test 3 fails with same object object error. So, possibly something related to Karma not seeing the DOM in Travis CI for some reason?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Full disclosure, I'm the guy that fixed this problem with Justin.*

The problem is that we were importing modules into our unit tests. These modules have a component that has `ngOnInit` which makes an HTTP request. The module injects the real component into the test and it tries to make its HTTP request but fails. Because it's out of the normal stack, the stack trace gives us the very unhelpful error `Uncaught [object Object]`.

In order to avoid that problem and for the component to not be undefined we use Christian Nunciato's helpful [ng2-mock-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-mock-component) library to make a mock component that takes all the same inputs.

Because the mocked component has its own unit tests, we don't care if the unit tests on the parent component don't test the child at the same time.

Comment: What if this problem occurs testing a service (provider) instead of a component?

Comment: @BecarioSenior Sounds like you're hitting another real service, which might be making an HTTP request or manipulating the window. Try and mock out any other service dependencies when creating the TestBed.configurationTestingModule. Something like what is described here https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/320

Answer (score 40):

This is what fixed it for me:

I searched the whole project for occurrences of `HttpClientModule` in all `*.spec.ts` files. Turned out I had a few!

Then I replaced all occurrences of

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

with

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
```

And then I made sure that the entry in the `imports` array of each of my test's `TestBed.configureTestingModule` was changed from `HttpClientModule` to `HttpClientTestingModule`.

And finally I turned my Wifi off and ran the tests again. And voilà: It worketh!

Comment: Thank you! Turned out my problem was also in relation to HttpModule, which was used through another module and which wasn't mocked with `HttpClientTestingModule`.

Comment: We had the same problem, but with providers of `HttpClient` and `HttpHandler` not the module. So you also have to check your spec-files for occurrences of `HttpClient` and `HttpHandler`. Remove them and import `HttpClientModule`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the Problem was that a component test, with child-components that make a http call in their ngOnInit method, did not have the HttpClientTestingModule imported. 
If you run the tests and open the devtools on the network page you can check if http calls are made during the tests. Once the module was imported no http calls were made during the tests.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way you can have this error too :

For me it was that I forgot to make the call to

```
    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      });
    });
```

My guess is that if this is not called it gets the NgModule from the AppModule and thus trying to import all the modules in there which cause this problem