# Angular8 Test different results for each run

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, gitlab-ci-runner

I've joined a project based in Angular8.

Every time I run the tests I get a different results in my local machine. 
When I push my branch, in the Gitlab runner, I also have different results.

This is the way that we run the tests:

```
ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI
```

Those are the versions that we use:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/node": "^10.14.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.10.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "~0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.7",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.3",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2"
  }
```

Sometimes I understand the test errors, like :

```
TheComponent should create FAILED
    Uncaught [object Object] thrown
```

I fixed that way:

```
if (eOneObject && eOneObject.length > 0) {
```

I added the `if (eOneObject` to the condition, so the Test is fixed.

But then, I have some errors in other components that have already passed the tests for my colleagues, like :

```
MessageComponent should create FAILED
    Uncaught [object Object] thrown
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'message-component',
  templateUrl: './message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message.component.css'],
  host: { '(window:resize)': 'onResize($event)' }
})
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MessageComponent>,
    public sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

This MessageComponent has "nothing" in the code. And it passed the tests for my colleagues.

I can't understand:

- Why I get different results in local tests and Gitlab runner (when the versions are equal)
- Why my branch (on Gitlab runner) is throwing error in tests components that are ok in my colleagues tests
- Is `ng test` randomly checking the components? I mean. Is it not testing everything in each run?

I'm sorry but I could'nt find a answer for all this problems. 
Thanks in advance.

Tests :

```
describe('MessageComponent', () => {
  let component: MessageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MessageComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ BrowserAnimationsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, MaterialWrapperModule, BrowserDynamicTestingModule ],
      declarations: [ MessageComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useCase: {} },
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useCase: {} }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MessageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

```
describe('TheComponent', () => {
  let component: TheComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TheComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MaterialWrapperModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [TheComponent],
      providers: [ErService, PrService, VtService, TService]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TheComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: without test code, it is not clear what you do so I would assume and give some points to try:
1) TestBed ... `compileComponents` should be inside `async` function,
2) fixture.detectChanges() in beforeEach causes triggering ngOnInit and it would cause your error(to avoid it use default value)
3) provide tests, if possible, cause those are only assumptions

Comment: @andriishupta Thanks for your comment. I've added my tests.

Comment: I've found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101519/karma-start-fails-headlesschrome-error-uncaught-object-object (Second answer). It seems that could be my issue. Cause I'm adding ```HttpClientModule``` in every spec.ts file.

Comment: In tests `HttpClientTestingModule` should be added instead, but in case of component - mock all services and you wouldn't need "HTTP provider"

Comment: Testing components is about testing component's state/html, and all incoming stuff should be mocked such as component is only a representation(which could be mocked). You could read some guides about different testing of Components/Services/other stuff such as there would clear up some points of testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason why `MessageComponent` fails is that `host: { '(window:resize)': 'onResize($event)' }` is not valid here, such component doesn't have `onResize` method + `$event` is not defined(right IDE should have highlight things like this).

Second reason: `useCase: {}`(should be `useValue`) is not valid; check [references](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers)

Next error: `providers: [ErService, PrService, VtService, TService]`, are not mocked and could do some non-needed stuff. Please, check [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing) to see how mocking is done for services and in general guide would help understand more how to test different parts of the application

The last one: check this [Karma Start Fails - HeadlessChrome - ERROR Uncaught [object Object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101519/karma-start-fails-headlesschrome-error-uncaught-object-object)

`TheComponent` could do so(no code provided), but looking on services - I think this could be the case

Hope this would help :)

Comment: chaning to the HttpClientTestingModule was the solution for me. Thanks!